# ng-repeat with chips in angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to use md-chips to collect input from user with auto-complete. For ex: price,available,Y,N. where each component will be rendered in chips.There will be multiple inputs from user per line. When i submit the form i need all the chips per line entered by user. This is where i'm facing the problem.

```
<div ng-repeat ="rule in rules">
<md-chips ng-model="selectedHeaders">
<md-chip-template>
{{$chip}}
</md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
</div>
```

the above code works as my model is just selectheader and in js it's
$scope.selectedHeaders = [];
how should i use it to for rule.selectheader??. If i change my model to rule.selectheader , it throws this below error

Cannot set property 'selectedHeaders' of undefined.
Any pointers to solve this issue will be much apppreciated. If issue is not clear, please ask

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined **rules** values?

In js, at least the value of rules must be something like this

```
var rules = [{
    selectedHeaders: ['Apple', 'Orange']
}, {
    selectedHeaders: ['Banana']
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below

**Js code**

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.rules = [{
      name: 'rule1',
      id: 1
    }, {
      name: 'rule2',
      id: 2
    }];
    $scope.data = {};

  });
```

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl1'>
      <div ng-repeat="rule in rules">
        <md-chips ng-model="data.selectedHeaders">
          <md-chip-template>
            {{$chip}}
            <!-- for testing-->{{rule}}
          </md-chip-template>
        </md-chips>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the link [Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/81abbca5/1/)